# xtext - Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'scoping.ImportNamespacesScopingFragment'

Tags: xtext

I try to add this code to my mwe2 file:

```
                fragment = scoping.ImportNamespacesScopingFragment {}
                fragment = exporting.QualifiedNamesFragment {}
                fragment = builder.BuilderIntegrationFragment {}
```

I am following this (I try that import would work in my language): [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/308240/).
but I get an error Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'scoping.ImportNamespacesScopingFragment'. This is the error:

```
0    [main] ERROR mf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher  - [XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:55 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'scoping.ImportNamespacesScopingFragment'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:56 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'exporting.QualifiedNamesFragment'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:57 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'builder.BuilderIntegrationFragment'.]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:55 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'scoping.ImportNamespacesScopingFragment'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:56 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'exporting.QualifiedNamesFragment'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:57 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'builder.BuilderIntegrationFragment'.]
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
```

What should I do?

Comment: which xtext version do you use?

Comment: And what is your actual goal. These fragments are default since xtext 2.0. And they are part of the old generator (org.eclipse.xtext.generator) which was replaced by (org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator) in newer 2.9+ versions and thus must be added as dependency explicitly

Comment: I am using xtext 2.10 version. I try that the rule `Import:
 'import' importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildcard ('as' name=ID)?` will work in my language. now it's not recognize other files in my DSL project (I changed the default of global scoping of all files) I want that if I have word 'import file1' it will recognize the objects in this file from the current file. In addition I tried instead of importedNamespace to use importURI but I get an error 'import resource cannot be found'

Comment: well the point is: how did you implement the as thing. and; import a.b.c.* makes name like a.b.c.D visible under its simple name D so if you dont have qualified names like filename.element name in the index (iqualifiednameprovider) then this would be a useless thing.
if you want to use import uri based scoping you have to bind ImportUriGlobalScopeProvider https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1736352/?srch=ImportUriGlobalScopeProvider#msg_1736352

Comment: if I just do `'import' importURI=QualifiedNameWithWildcard TOK_SEMI;` without the 'as'. It's still doesn't work for me. I added to myDslRuntimeModule the bindIQualifiedNameProvider,configureIScopeProviderDelegate, bindIGlobalScopeProvider like in the link you added but it's still doesn't work. I wrote in my dsl file: import folder1.folder2.filename.myDsl. it's keep telling me that import resource cannot be found.. am I missing something? `QualifiedNameWithWildcard:
 QualifiedName '.*'?;
QualifiedName:
 TypeConstantLiteral ('.' TypeConstantLiteral)*;`

Comment: and `TypeConstantLiteral:
 ID | INT | 'FALSE' | 'TRUE';`

Comment: import uri und import namespace are two different things. either import uri based scoping or imported namespace based scoping. import uri is `importURI=STRING` imported namespace  is `importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildcard`

Comment: I changed to importURI=STRING... `import "fileBoo.dsl"//full path: "folderBoo1.folderBoo2.fileBoo.dsl"

module Foo

input boolean[4] request;
input Int(0..4) currentFloor;

output {UP, DOWN, STOP} motor;

guarantee foo:
  boo(motor=STOP, request[0], currentFloor=0); //boo is from fileBoo` and it say couldn't resolve reference to boo. I don't understand what am I doing wrong or missing  (I followed  the linke you added and did what you wrote there to do)

Comment: did you change the global scope provider?

Comment: Yes you right I forgot I changed it to NullGlobalScopeProvider.. now I deleted it and it's still doesn't work. I need to change it to something else? I am need to write after import the all path or partial path? it doesnt work any way... if I have a file that it's path is /iSynthExamples/pattern/DwyerPatterns.spectra how I need to write it after the 'import'?

Comment: can you please share a complete sample project (dsl + model project) i can simply clone and look at

Comment: this is example in my language [example](http://pastebin.com/GXHh62mv). and here is part of my grammar [grammar](http://pastebin.com/50fCJM9t). sorry it's not the full grammar, I don't have permission to publish the full version (It's not mine). I hope it's enough information that you will understand the situation

Comment: sry i need code that i can run. did you add all 3 bindings mentioned in the eclipse forum post?

Comment: Ok this is the full grammar http://pastebin.com/9RLp7beQ  and this is the example: http://pastebin.com/twAx4tjR

Comment: works fine for me. no errors ```class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {
 
 override bindIGlobalScopeProvider() {
  ImportUriGlobalScopeProvider
 }

 override configureIScopeProviderDelegate(Binder binder) {
  binder.bind(IScopeProvider).annotatedWith(Names.named(AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider.NAMED_DELEGATE)).to(
   SimpleLocalScopeProvider);
 }

 override bindIQualifiedNameProvider() {
  SimpleNameProvider
 }
}```

Comment: it's recognize you atMostTwoPbetweenQandR? I wrote two files in the same link but it's should be two different files in two different folders like this: [file1](http://pastebin.com/hjm6E4Sj) and [file2](http://pastebin.com/twAx4tjR). It's still doesn't recognize it to me.. I added those methods.

Comment: How is the folder structure for the files

Comment: and i had to add a module xxxxx to the imported file

Comment: If I put both files in the same folder the import is working. but if they in different folder it's not working. If I have parent folder name 'iSynthExamples' and I have folder 'imports' in it I have the file 'Elevator.spectra' and I have in 'iSynthExamples' another folder named 'patterns' and in it I have the file DwyerPatterns.spectra. I changed the 'import "patterns.DwyerPatterns.spectra" ' so it could know the location of the DwyerPatterns.spectra file.. it's still doesnt work for me

Comment: Well then you import is wrong. The import uri is a relative uri. That THE feature of importUri

Comment: so how I should do this kind of import?

Comment: i dont get your requirements in the first place. can you elaborate how your imports should work

Comment: I want that if I have file1 in folder1 that 'import **some path to file2 in folder 2 that would work**' will work. both files are diffrenete and the folders can be diffrente and can be the same(if it's in the same folder the importURI is good and it's work fine!) but if the files in different folders I want it to work too... there is some import with full path or something that will work for what I want?

Comment: I want it to work like in Java

Comment: i still cannot folllow you `import "../other/DwyerPatterns.mydsl2"import "../other/DwyerPatterns.mydsl2"`works. `import "platform:/resource/example/src/other/DwyerPatterns.mydsl2"`works as well. 

what i want to understand is: what are your actual requirements behind the import thing

Comment: but java is namespace imports. and java imports work out of the box with no bindings as i said before `importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildcard`

Comment: sorry about the confusion you are right as always :) Thank you very much!!!